# Browser error: Unable to find application named 'Google Chrome'

Tags: pycharm, apple-m1

I can't get Pycharm properly configured on my macbook M1 such that I can use Google Chrome. Each time I run a script, I get the same message: "Browser error: Unable to find application named Google Chrome". I tried to follow this post without success:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206844095-Browser-error-Unable-to-find-application-named-open-Play-framework-2-0

I went to web Browsers and Preview, change the default browser to Custom Path and left the other fields to Open. What did I forget to do?